# How do I ignore a module .git directory?

Tags: drush, version-control

I've got a Drupal 8 installation that I manage with Drush 8.1.2, with nothing in that installation in Git except a custom module I am writing (module directory = location of `.git` directory = `/sites/all/modules/mymodulename`).

Whenever I do a `drush pm-update` it complains about my module:

> Project was not packaged by drupal.org but obtained from git. You need to enable git_deploy module

I don't see how I can follow the suggestion of `git_deploy` which, as far as I can tell, provides an update source for modules checked out of drupal.org... so how can I let Drush know that my module is a stand-alone Git installation, and stop it from generating that warning every time?

The `--lock` option to `drush pm-update` is probably not appropriate, since my module is neither a core or a contrib module, and it doesn't change the warning in any case.  The only thing I've found to make that warning go away is to delete or rename the module's `.git` directory.

**p.s.**, one thing I noticed later: the warning also goes away if the module is uninstalled: probably because uninstalled modules aren't checked for upgrades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct; git_deploy is only useful for projects that are ultimately hosted on drupal.org.  The pm-* commands only operate on drupal.org projects, and have no facility for ignoring projects from other sources.  This is a limitation of Drush; improvements in this area would be welcome.

Comment: thanks @greg_1_anderson - there are some threads and issues indicating the `--lock` option was slow growing and undocumented, but why doesn't `drush pm-update --lock=mymodulename` suppress checking my module? Would be helpful for me to know the exact behaviour.